# Which is more efficient in terms of comparison in JavaScript, "includes()" or "=="?

Tags: javascript

Yes, I realize that "includes()" is not necessarily used for comparison. I also realize this may be a very question. However, in my particular case, I am using it to distinguish whether or not a particular string in an array contains an identifying substring of text. In short, I have two functions that return arrays of size 3. I have the option to stick a blank parameter in one, such as changing:

```
my2ndFunction("identifying string",1000,true);
```

to:

```
my2ndFunction("useless parameter","identifying string",1000,true);
```

The purpose of this would be to distinguish the two functions (the one above and the other one of 3 arguments) by a check like this:

```
if(arguments.length == 4){}
else{}
```

Or, would it be faster to simply leave the arguments at 3, and do this:

```
if(arguments[0].includes("identifying")){}
else{}
```

Also, feel free to edit the particular way I asked the question if it is not clear.

Comment: these type of things are not where someone should be focussing on efficiency, at least in this example. Both options work fast enough. In this case, startsWith should be better than includes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that both are okay, and it depends on the use case of your function.

If you are using the first one (==), you test only on the number of your function's parameters and it will work even if your fourth parameter is something else than an "identifying" object.
the thing than will not raise an error if you are passing another type than "identifying".

In the other hand, using includes() will test if your first parameter is an "identifying" object and if you are passing only three parameters it will work !!

It really depends on your use case and you should pay attention to your calls; Else you will loose time to identify why your code is not working.